# Running Mac OS X under KVM/QEMU

Tags: linux, osx, kvm, virtualization, qemu

**Note to be removed in the future, so as to avoid confusion from answerers and mods**

edit: Forgot to add in the note, if anyone thinks this is the wrong stack-site to post this, please comment on why, and which one would be better, as I thought pretty hard about this. :D

I find a lack of information regarding running Mac OS on Linux using KVM/QEMU. My objective is to create a good knowledgebase to run it under Linux on "weird architectures", and I'm running Arch on an AMD Processor (Phenom II X6) I decided it would be a nice opportunity to build this knowledgebase, amassing as much info as possible.

I'm interested in making this as complete as possible, so any tips/hints regarding architectures unsupported by MacOS (i.e. AMD Processors) as well as perks of specific Linux Distributions (Such as Ubuntu, Fedora etc.) are welcome. Help from anyone having such knowledge from experience will also be really appreciated. As happy as I can be for any help, I do not intend to accept half-good answers as I expect this question to outline general issues for different systems and architectures, but I can and will accept answers as long as answerer contributes to the discussion and is willing to work with adding that information if needed be.

If no one can properly answer this, I intend to answering it with my findings, but I will neither refuse help nor refuse to accept answers that satisfy the criteria outlined in this note.

**End of note, now for the question itself**

Considering all the intricacies of setting up Mac OS X to run over Linux, with Mac OS being built for specific Apple Hardware, which would be the most efficient but still generic way to configure it so as to run on as many linux distributions as possible, even under architectures unsupported by apple (Such as AMD processors and such other hardware)? I hope we can avoid hacks so as to keep it consistent with different versions of software, kernels and package managers, but realize this may be impossible.

I intend to find a solution for the latest Mac OS release, no need to support previous versions of Mac OS, and using newer features of Linux systems is also not an issue as long as they are standard linux and not distribution-specific, as everyone wil catch up eventually.

Please avoid answers that require specific hardware or distros (Due to distribution-specific coding that may be uncompatible with other distros) to work. This basically translates to: If it works on Ubuntu and not on Debian, it's not good.